# Python Bokeh send additional parameters to widget event handler

Tags: python, events, bokeh

I want to send additional data to a bokeh event handler (e.g. an on_change or on_click method).  A minimal example that increments or decrements an integer is below (I run this app with 'bokeh serve --show app.py).  I had to write separate event handlers that do almost identical things in this example.  To write this app with just one event handler function, I need to pass additional data or the event handler must know the calling object.  How do I do that?

```
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button, Paragraph
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox

minus = Button(label='-')
plus = Button(label='+')
text = Paragraph(text='0')

def minus_callback():
    text.text = str(int(text.text) - 1)

def plus_callback():
    text.text = str(int(text.text) + 1)

minus.on_click(minus_callback)
plus.on_click(plus_callback)
# I would prefer to just use one callback and pass additional data to it:
# minus.on_click(callback, action='decrement')
# plus.on_click(callback, action='increment')

layout = widgetbox(minus, plus, text)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The standard [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)  facility that is built into python works fine with Bokeh callbacks.

```
from functools import partial
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button, Paragraph
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox

minus = Button(label='-')
plus = Button(label='+')
text = Paragraph(text='0')

def callback(foo):
    print(foo)

minus.on_click(partial(callback, foo="minus"))
plus.on_click(partial(callback, foo="plus"))

layout = widgetbox(minus, plus, text)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer - functools partial also works well with Bokeh FunctionHandler to pass kwargs when running a server application within Jupyter, so the function in [this](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/0.12.5/examples/howto/server_embed/notebook_embed.ipynb) code could have variables passed to it...

Comment: How can we make it work with `on_change` with `attr="value"`?

Comment: `attr` is a parameter of `on_change`, not of the callback. It always has to be supplied: `plus.on_change('value', partial(callback, foo="plus"))`

Comment: I am trying to pass a pandas dataframe as input parameters - but I got "TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed" - code snipped: https://gist.github.com/6f5f20a270d6ecb92afd22be22edfa83  should I open a new question?

Answer (score 0):

Extending on [@bigreddot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41939824/3585557), this code outputs the updated value to the `text` attribute of the `Paragraph` object.

```py
from functools import partial
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button, Paragraph
from bokeh.layouts import column


def callback(update):
    text.text = str(int(text.text) + update)


minus = Button(label='-')
plus = Button(label='+')
text = Paragraph(text='0')
minus.on_click(partial(callback, update=-1))
plus.on_click(partial(callback, update=+1))

layout = column(minus, plus, text)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```